# django rest framework TokenAuthentication not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Want to use token base authentication system so api call for get list using DRF , It always throw error , I test this api in local system.

"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."

Setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',        
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',        
    ),

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',

    ),       
}
```

Serializer.py

```
class MyListSerializer(SignUpSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyMod
        fields = ('no', 'yes')
```

view.py

```
class MyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = MyMod.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyListSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

url:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MDgYnKeoRsp0O4Hfgr9ka5tdfkKs6Y" http://127.0.0.1:8000/my/
```

Error:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Comment: Aren't you mixing OAuth2Authentication and TokenAuthentication ? for TokenAuthentication, you should use this header : Authorization: Token MDgYnKeoRsp0O4Hfgr9ka5tdfkKs6Y ("Token", not "Bearer")

Comment: thanks for reply , according to you : curl -i -H "Authorization: Token MDgYnKeoRsp0O4Hfgr9ka5tdfkKs6Y" http://127.0.0.1:8000/my/   same error    {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud is right way to use TokenAuthentication in class view.

Comment: Prefixing Authorization header value with 'Token ' is the right way but how did you get "MDgYnKeoRsp0O4Hfgr9ka5tdfkKs6Y" ? you should use something like : Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user).key   . Is it the case ?

Comment: main problem with permission permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope] instead of authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem :

```
class MyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = MyMod.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyListSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

Solution:

```
class MyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = MyMod.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyListSerializer
    permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope]
```

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MDgYnKeoRsp0O4Hfgr9ka5tdfkKs6Y" http://127.0.0.1:8000